# Setting default headers in Rails3 applications

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know that you can set default headers application wide in `config/application.rb` for Rails4+ apps but what is the accepted method in older versions of Rails, as in Rails3?

At the moment I am setting them in application_controller.rb as a before_filter method, but I think this is a bad practices and performance 
-impacting

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter#default-headers

Comment: Did you benchmark the performance difference? What makes you say your current implementation is not performant? What *is* your current implementation? What *is* the performance?

Comment: @TomLord I have nothing to compare it with. At the moment, the only way I know how to set default headers is in the application_controller in a method which is called before each and every request my Rails app receives.

My application_controller is already bursting with before_filter methods which I am slowly trying to remove (where possible)

Comment: Documentation on Rails4 seems to indicate that this shouldnt be part of the application_controller at all. Wondering how other developers on older versions of Rails solved this issue. Middleware? Alternative configurations? Maybe my solution is the accepted standard, I would like to receive validation from others if so

Comment: *"I have nothing to compare it with."* -- Well, that's not true... You can compare the performance of your own application with and without the `before_filter` method. But I'm not the best person to ask for validation on rails 3 best practices; I haven't used it in over 5 years.

Answer (score 1):

Before filter seems like the correct way in Rails 3.  However, you MIGHT be able to monkey patch this. You'll probably need to check if this has changed. But [looking at this code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L135) on 3.2 stable you may be able to set headers here.  Even if this works, it may not have any impact on performance.

You could try to put this in a monkey patch in:

```
# config/initializers/monkey_patch_headers.rb
class ActionController::Metal
  def initialize
    @_headers = {
      "Content-Type" => "text/html",
      "Foo" => "bar" # or whatever you want to add
     }
    @_status = 200
    @_request = nil
    @_response = nil
    @_routes = nil
    super
  end
end
```

Now inside any controller action you should see them in `@_headers`.
I have no idea if this will break anything else. Might be worth a try.